# How to make recursive portals?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I want to make see-through portals, as seen in the game Portal, but allow it to have support for portal recursion (i.e. seeing portals through portals)

I'd prefer it to be in the Eevee render engine, and want to avoid using more than two cameras and compositing them together if possible.

Bonus points if light can pass through the portals, but it's not required.

Comment: maybe add some links to animations how it should look like?

Comment: https://youtu.be/PkGjYig8avo?t=1064 this is ideally what I'm looking for (yes I know it's in unity but I couldn't find anything in blender that wasn't compositing the 2 views and it usually wasnt recursive)

Comment: I know I'll likely have to fake passing through them but I'm just looking for the visuals of it at the current moment

Comment: Due to the physically based rendering of both eevee and cycles it's really really hard to do this kind of effect in Blender, I'd say its even impossible to do it in real time. You may have better luck by using a dedicated game engine with render textures like Unity or Unreal Engine.